# Cannot access object specific properties via props in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-class-based-component

//Calling props value inside componentDidMount[Here i am able to access the value of others but when i access widget.data i got indefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlydz.png)

```
componentDidMount(){
        const widget = this.props.widgets.filter(widget => widget.id === this.state.widgetId)[0];  
       console.log('object',widget);
       console.log('widget.description---',widget.description);
       console.log('widget.code-------',widget.code);
       console.log('widget.componentName----',widget.componentName)
    
       console.log('widget.data',widget.Data);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Properties in JavaScript are case-sensitive. Therefore, you have to use `widget.data` instead of `widget.Data`.

Comment: i have tried both widget.data, widget.Data, widget._data, widget._Data but still got same result